# Can I/how do I configure git extensions to show, within windows explorer, which directories have been touched?

Tags: git, windows-explorer, git-extensions

I'm wondering if I can/how can I configure git extensions to, when I explore a file system with windows explorer, show me which directories/files have git repositories in them, and, of those which have repositories, which have been touched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible with GitExtensions

---

You might want to use **[TortoiseGit](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/)** for that kind of integration with the Windows Explorer.

[image: https://www.openshift.com/sites/default/files/Explorer2_0.png]

Comment: I'd much prefer not to switch to Tortoise - is that the only alternative? I know GitExtensions can have "plugins", but I can't seem to find a repository of plugins anywhere

Comment: @blueberryfields that is the only alternative I am aware of, for adding overlays to a Windows Explorer. But maybe someone else will have a different answer.